# Love letter number two

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

Dearest Zipporah,

I apologize for the delay. I finally deciphered your message. While I had hoped it was you that sent the letter, I was glad to see that it indeed was your father's name that you encoded in your letter.

I myself am not quite adept with words, and you aren't either, as been proved in your letter. I regret to inform you that I, in reality, have no potatoes to bring with me on the twenty sixth. Although I know that you love them, I'm pained to admit that my refrigerator broke down and I had to throw all my food out, including the potatoes.

In the mean time, I tried my best to create a puzzle for you so you can solve it whilst you wait. It is a three word confession that I am quite pained to admit to you.

To write my puzzle, I did a bit of recon and found out what books you've been watching lately. Each word of the sentence is in each of the three paragraphs, one for each one.

The chemical symbol of the element with the electron configuration of [Kayar] for-dee^tin fireess^too firepea^fire.

The country in the Caribbean that experienced  an earthquake in the year factorized as 2•3•5•67, minus the most used letter in the English alphabet.

Then, what vegetable does Matt Smith liken Sontarans too? Then add an s.

Oh, the lengths I go to gain your affection, now all in vain. Don't hold this letter as a slight against me.

Love, 
Henry

P. S. Aren't you the one with Moses?

Comment: I've seen ... most of the puzzles here, and this is the first one I'd actually say is *in character*, as opposed to *ostensibly written by a character*

Comment: I love watching books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confession is

> I hate potatoes

The first one is

> I, for Iodine, which has electron configuration $[Kr] 4d^{10}5s^{2}5p^{5}$, which is basically what's written read phonetically and transcribed.

The second one is

> Haiti, minus the final syllable, a long E sound.

The last one is basically a freebie from

> [The Snowmen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUrMOcjMHoE)

Comment: lol oops, you beat me to it

Comment: Nice job, I suppose it was a bit too easy. I enjoy watching books in my free time as well.